# Adding a function call to a prefabbed button in Unity

Tags: unity, c#, gui

For each of my scenes, I have an empty GameObject `_Manager` that stores my scripts for setting up the level, keeping track of variables, etc.

On my main screen, I have a play button that isn't instantiated; I simply dragged it into the editor. In my script `Main.cs` I have a function `Play()` which calls `LoadLevel("Game")`. To get my play button to call the Play function, I dragged `_Manager` into the onClick slot and selected the function. This worked fine and I have a functional play button.

Unfortunately, this is not working for the prefabbed buttons I need to instantaite in my Game scene. In `Game.cs` I have a function `LayoutButtons()` which is both public and returns void, yet I am unable to drag `_Manager` into the slot on my prefabbed button. Even if I do it before converting the button to a prefab, it simply disappears once it becomes a prefab.

I've managed to work around this by putting my `LayoutButtons()` function in a new script which I attached directly to the prefab, but I'd like to keep the function within `Game.cs` and attached to my manager object if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to Setup play as a public void Play() so when you drag the manager to the click event you can see Play() on the list.

Edit: If you are using a prefabbed button you want to also use a prefabbed manager and drag that into the button click event to work properly.

```
public void Play()
{
     LoadLevel("Game");
}
```

Comment: Perhaps my wall of text was confusing. Your code is exactly what I have working. The problem I'm having is that I have other buttons (prefabbed) that don't allow me to do this same thing.

Comment: you would need to have the manager prefabbed and drag the prefabbed version into the click event to call.

Answer (score 1):

If you instantiate the button you can get a reference to it, like `GameObject _Button = Instantiate(_ButtonPrefab)` and then you can call `_Button.AddListener(//A Method on this script)` to add a new method to the button, which just does the same as clicking on the plus, dragging in a game object and choosing a method.

I don't know if this is still helpful for you or not, but it's better to use `SceneManager` to load scenes, instead of `LoadLevel`, because `LoadLevel` is old.